# Calling ActiveX component from WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Currently I am working on a POC which needs to communicate to a third party ActiveX component via wcf service. It all works fine when I test this using WCF test client but the moment I call the wcf service method from an ASP.Net page, the system crashes, a timeout exception is returned.

It works fine in the below scenarios:

1. WCF Test Client---WCF Service--ActiveX Component
2. Windows Application-->WCF Service-->ActiveX Component
3. ASP.Net-->ActiveX Component

It does not work only in for the below scenario :

ASP.Net-->WCF Service-->ActiveX Component

I have been struggling with this for quite a some time, any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: may be a permission issue? Both test and win App run in your account. Aspnet runs in low priv account

Comment: thanks for your response.Do you mean I need to impersonate my account

Comment: May be. Try it, its a shot in the dark